# Mysql Find free time (slots) between appointments for booking system

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I'm trying to find the free time slots between 2 datetime field that match a specific duration for a booking system, but I'am stuck on the correct query.

my db Events:

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| Event_ID | StartTime           | EndTime             | Pers_ID |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
|        3 | 2013-09-21 16:00:00 | 2013-09-21 16:30:00 |       6 | 
|       21 | 2013-09-21 09:00:00 | 2013-09-21 09:15:00 |       6 | 
|        5 | 2013-09-21 09:15:00 | 2013-09-21 10:15:00 |       6 | 
|       64 | 2013-09-21 15:00:00 | 2013-09-21 15:45:00 |       6 | 
|       32 | 2013-09-21 10:15:00 | 2013-09-21 11:30:00 |       6 | 
|        6 | 2013-09-21 13:00:00 | 2013-09-21 14:45:00 |       6 | 
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

The result must be the  free possible slots of 75 minutes with Pers_ID=6 between 2013-09-21 09:00:00 AND 2013-09-21 22:00:00 , and also they have to start right after an EndTime already in the database

Already thanks for the help,
E-raser

Comment: How many records does the table contain?

Comment: Hi Raymond,

+- 5000 records
and about 20 receords a day

Br,
E-raser

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AvailStartTime, AvailEndTime
FROM (
    SELECT @lastEndTime as AvailStartTime, StartTime as AvailEndTime, @lastEndTime := EndTime
    FROM (SELECT StartTime, EndTime
          FROM Events
          WHERE Pers_ID = 6
            AND EndTime >= '2013-09-21 09:00'
            AND StartTime < '2013-09-21 22:00'
          ORDER BY StartTime) e
    JOIN (SELECT @lastEndTime := NULL) init) x
WHERE AvailEndTime > DATE_ADD(AvailStartTime, INTERVAL 75 MINUTE)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a666/10)

Comment: @E-raser  PRIMARY KEY(Event_ID), KEY(Pers_ID, StartTime, EndTime) you need these indexes so it needs two full tables scan instead off three but this is still not good if your tables are large

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thanks for your help but there is still something wrong, in [this example] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d743c/18) i'am looking for timeslots of 30 minutes, there should be the following slots: starting at 9:15,starting at 11:30 and also the last one starting at 16:30, but this last one is missing.

Comment: It can only find slots between two events, since it's comparing each row to the next to see if there's room. It won't find slots after the last event or before the first, since there's nothing to compare against.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the info, if you have another solution, feel free...
The timeslots of x minutes should be between 2 dates like 2013-09-21 09:00 and 2013-09-21 22:00 and start right after an EndTime already in the db Events

Comment: Hey, I'm a little late to this post, but thanks for the amazing solution! Do you know if there is a way to add looking for open appointments before and after the filled time-slots, or how you might return all the available time if no slots are booked in mysql? Would rather handle it in 1 sql query rather than multiple ones for efficiency.

Comment: @Roni If you have MySQL 8.x I think you can use the `LAG()` window function.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the suggestion @Barmar, I'll have to check on that, in the end at least for my use case I needed to deal with locations , people and break times for the people working, so I actually made different types of events "bounding events".

For example, a staff member would check post their start and stop time at a specific location in essence their availability, as well as other downtimes like breaks or pre-existing meetings. Rather than storing that data separately I just used that to create boundaries.

Comment: continued ... if you start at 9 and end at 5 and are unavailable from 12-1 all at location 1 then you availability now shows perfectly because there is a bounding "start" appointment for you that ends at 9am and a bounding stop appointment that ends at 5pm and of course the break that you've added in. By adapting that into the prior logic, this solution became the perfect solution for all my needs!

Thanks for posting your prior solution it made a tricky problem into a quick work!
Much appreciated 