# MySQL query for available days and time slots

Tags: php, mysql

I am needing to access two tables from the existing database: ea_user_settings and ea_appointments

The data in those tables looks like this:

```
ea_user_settings
id_users_provider   working_plan
85                  {"sunday":null,"monday":null,"tuesday":{"start":"11:00","end":"19:00","breaks":[{"start":"16:00","end":"17:00"},{"start":"13:00","end":"14:00"}]},"wednesday":null,"thursday":null,"friday":null,"saturday":null}
```

The breaks variable ranges from [] to as many as the privider schedules.

```
ea_appointments
id  start_datetime              end_datetime               id_users_provider
1   '2015-09-08 14:00:00:00'   '2015-09-08 14:50:00:00'    85
2   '2015-09-08 15:00:00:00'   '2015-09-08 15:50:00:00'    85
3   '2015-09-17 12:00:00:00'   '2015-09-17 15:50:00:00'    89
4   '2015-09-17 16:00:00:00'   '2015-09-17 16:30:00:00'    89
5   '2015-09-22 11:00:00:00'   '2015-09-08 11:50:00:00'    85
6   '2015-09-22 12:00:00:00'   '2015-09-08 12:50:00:00'    85
7   '2015-09-22 14:00:00:00'   '2015-09-08 14:50:00:00'    85
8   '2015-09-22 15:00:00:00'   '2015-09-08 15:50:00:00'    85
9   '2015-09-22 17:00:00:00'   '2015-09-08 17:50:00:00'    85
10  '2015-09-22 18:00:00:00'   '2015-09-08 18:50:00:00'    85
```

I need a MySQL query that will yield the following:
For provider 85 between 2015-09-07 and 2015-09-23 how many available 60 min slots exist.  Result would look like this:

```
id_users_provider    available_days   available_slots
85                   2015-09-08       4
85                   2015-09-15       6
```

I see this [Mysql Find free time (slots) between appointments for booking system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934143/mysql-find-free-time-slots-between-appointments-for-booking-system)  and other similar posts.  This helps me see how I can extract availability between existing appointments.  I also see that I would need to join that with a table expressing the providers working plan.  I am not sure how to extract the working plan into a table to join and produce the result.  So, any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: how about a multi thousand row table with day, slot for a left join. Want one? It is screaming fast

Comment: 1. I don't see '2015-09-15' in the table. how is it been shown in the expected results? 2. how do you count slots?

Comment: Thanks, it exists within the providers working plan.  As I am thinking about this I think I will need to pull the working plan into PHP and then explode that that into an array in php (Sunday-Sat x start and end times), then adjust that to the current calendar date,  and then add the ea_appointments array in to that.  Then I will have to spot the available time between all of that and divide that time by 60.  I do not think I can do it all with a MySQL query.